# Which is better between using long string key or short string key in HashMap?

Tags: java, key, hashmap

Which is better between using long string key or short string key in HashMap?

Example:

## 1. Long string key in HashMap

```
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("[ART.117.4002] ADAPTER RUNTIME (ADAPTER SERVICE): UNABLE TO INVOKE ADAPTER SERVICE", "Cannot invoke adapter service");
```

Note: the long string would be limited to maximum 120 chars and all is uppercased. If the length is more than the max. chars, it will be truncated.

## 2. Short string key in HashMap

```
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("B8B77715", "Cannot invoke adapter service");
```

Note: the B8B77715 is a CRC32 of "[ART.117.4002] ADAPTER RUNTIME (ADAPTER SERVICE): UNABLE TO INVOKE ADAPTER SERVICE".

Let's say there would be 4000+ entries in the HashMap. Which is better between two in term of performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A CRC32 is a rough approximation of your original value, but it will be possible for two different original values to result in the same CRC32 value.  This makes them a very poor candidate for a key to a `HashMap` and the fact it reduces data integrity should trump any potential performance concerns.  Definitely use `[ART.117.4002] ...` -- why introduce a potential (if rare) bug when you don't need to?

That being said, the part in the beginning (between the square brackets) looks like it has the potential for being a unique identifier.  If that were so, you could see some (quite marginal) performance boosts by using just the token between the brackets (via string parsing) rather than that whole big string.

Comment: +1: using the hash of a hash won't improve the performance of your system and might degrade its reliability.

Comment: So you all propose to use long string as the key? Is it okay? Since logically it will eat many memory spaces if there are many entries in HashMap.

Comment: @suud, the most important point is that the CRC32 will eventually result in a broken program.  So that option should be immediately thrown out the window.  The next (possible) consideration is the size of the keys.  At that point -- it depends.  How many unique keys would you expect?  I'd say anything on the order of thousands would mean that this (modest) size of your key is inconsquential.  If you end up with millions, you might want to consider an optimization (but not the CRC32 solution!).

Comment: But unfortunately the key string is not always has a unique identifier in the bracket or such, it could be like this: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out" or "BATCH_DEL_DEPT_MEMBER_ALL_FAIL".

Comment: @suud, fair enough.  So how many unique keys could you realistically anticipate?

Comment: There is also another consideration apart from the length of the key. Keys in general are supposed to identify a record and not being updatable, you modify the value(s) not the key, while with a key like that I suspect there is something flawed in your program logic.

Comment: @stivlo, it looks to me like the OP is simply trying to maintain a mapping between machine-ugly error messages to more human-friendly ones.  If so, I think everything is pretty static and this approach is fine.

Comment: @kirk woll: yes, you're right, this is for mapping system error message to user-friendly error message. I expected there would be 8000+ unique keys in the future.

Comment: I'd say, don't do this. The "user friendly" message will be very unfriendly to techies, who can't google anymore the error or ask for advice on forums or SO. **It will be also of limited use to non-techies, because it's a 1 to 1 mapping**, while errors have to be translated to higher level logical level. But, I'll give you the benefit of the doubt, because maybe I don't understand your use case well.

Comment: @stivlo: the message is intended for end-user/customer actually. Don't worry for us programmers, we always have an access to the real error message :-)

Comment: @suud -- so ~8000 strings on the order of 100 characters each.  That's roughly on the order of about 1 meg of memory.  That's fairly modest, though admitedly not nothing.  I think your `HashMap` solution is fine, but if you were *really* concerned about memory, you could offload this data into a file (or better, a database) and fetch the mapping as needed.  This would reduce memory usage to nothing, but increase the cost of obtaining the mapping on each occurence.  If you believe these errors would happen only rarely, this could be a better approach.

Comment: @Kirk Woll: lol, actually the data itself come from database :))

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to imagine it could possibly matter. Use whatever makes the most sense.